# Getting main() method parameters from a heap dump

Tags: jvm, heap-dump

I have a Java binary heap dump file. Is there a generic way to find out the command line parameters that were passed in to the program's `main()` method?

I tend to use Eclipse MAT for working with heap dumps.

Comment: This answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/3675163/32090

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `main` thread is still alive then the arguments should be referenced on the heap. You should be able to find it using OQL statement like one mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3675163/32090